# find ${dy}/{dx}$ of $x\sqrt{1+y} + y\sqrt{1+x} = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

### Question

[image: question]

### My approach

[image: my approach]

I tried by applying basic product rule, but could not proceed further; don't know how to eliminate the y factors in the solution. How to prove it?

Comment: This isn't true when $x=y$, by the way.

Comment: [Please do not use images to conveyt critical information not otherwise present in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x \sqrt{1+y}= - y \sqrt{1+x}$$
Square on both the sides :
$$\Rightarrow x^2 (1+y)=y^2(1+x)$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2-y^2=xy^2-x^2y$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+y)(x-y)=xy(y-x)$$
$$\Rightarrow x+y=-xy$$
$$\Rightarrow y+xy=-x$$
$$\Rightarrow y (1+x)=-x$$
$$\Rightarrow y =\frac{-x}{1+x}$$
$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{x+1}-1$$

Now differentiate to get your result

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include the image of solution

Comment: You should preferable use Mathjax in place of images..

Comment: After last step, $\frac{-x}{x+1}=-1+\frac{1}{x+1} $

Comment: @Sahaj I completely missed your suggestions, I have made the necessary edit. 
Narasimham, I thought that would be an obvious step and hence left it for OP to figure out.... regardless I have included your suggestion in the edit too.

Answer (score 3):

$$x(1+y)^{\frac1{2}} +y(1+x)^{\frac1{2}}=0$$

$$x(1+y)^{\frac{1}{2}}=-y(1+x)^{\frac1{2}}$$

Squaring both sides:

$$x^2(1+y)=y^2(1+x)$$

$$x^2y+x^2=y^2x+y^2$$

$$x^2-y^2=xy^2-yx^2$$

$$(x+y)(x-y)=-xy(x-y)$$

$$(x+y)=-xy$$

$$x+xy+y=0$$

$$x+y(1+x)=0$$

$$y=\frac{-x}{1+x}$$

Differentiating w.r.t $x$ we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{d(\frac{x}{1+x})}{dx}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{(1+x)\frac{dx}{dx}-x\frac{d(1+x)}{dx}}{(1+x)^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1+x-x}{(1+x)^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

which is the required proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -2):

###### 1. Introduction

Summarizing the question to make the answer contained and easy to follow:
$$\text{Find }\frac{\displaystyle dy}{\displaystyle dx}
\text{ given that }x \sqrt{1+y} + y \sqrt{1+x} = 0 \text{ , }
-1 < x < 1
\tag{Eq. 1}$$

###### 2. Steps to Solve the Question: $\text{Find }\frac{\displaystyle dy}{\displaystyle dx}
\text{ given that }x \sqrt{1+y} + y \sqrt{1+x} = 0 \text{ , }
-1 < x < 1$

First it is possible to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ using the following steps that produce two solutions, at least one of which applies to Equation 1.  Dividing Equation 1 by 
$\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1+y}$ and moving the terms associated with $x$ to the right side of the equals sign results in the following Equations 2.
$$ \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y}}=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}}\longrightarrow 
\frac{y^2}{\left(1+y\right)}=\frac{x^2}{\left(1+x\right)}\tag{Eq. 2a}$$
$$ \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y}}=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}}\longrightarrow 
\frac{y^4}{\left(1+y\right)^2}
=\frac{x^4}{\left(1+x\right)^2}\tag{Eq. 2b}$$
Also observe that 
$\frac{(y+1)*(y-1)+1}{1+y}
=\frac{y^2}{1+y}=(y-1)+\frac1{1+y}$.  
And, from Equation 2, the same for the right factor in $x$ as $\frac{(x+1)*(x-1)+1}{1+x}
=\frac{x^2}{1+x}=(x-1)+\frac1{1+x}$. So, in Equation 3 both terms are set equal.
$$(y-1)+\frac1{1+y}=(x-1)+\frac1{1+x} \tag{Eq. 3}$$  
Now take the derivative of Equation 3 with respect to $x$ in Equations 4 as folows:
$$\frac{d}{dx}
\left((y-1)+\frac1{1+y}\right)
=\frac{d}{dx}\left((x-1)+\frac1{1+x}\right) \tag{Eq. 4a}$$  
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)*
\left(1-\frac1{\left(1+y\right)^2}\right)
=\left(1-\frac1{\left(1+x\right)^2}\right) \tag{Eq. 4b}$$  
Now,
$$
\left(\left(\frac{dy}{dx}+ \frac1{\left(1+x\right)^2} 
     \right) - 
\left(\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) 
           *\frac1{\left(1+y\right)^2} +1 \right)
     \right)=0
\tag{Eq. 5}$$
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx} +
           \left(1+y\right)^2 
       \right)=0
\tag{Eq. 6}$$
From Equation 2,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y^2}{1+y}\right)
=\left(\frac{2y*(1+y)-y^2}{\left(1+y\right)^2}\right)
*\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) \\
=\left(\frac{(y)*(y+2)}{\left(1+y\right)^2}\right)
*\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) 
=\left(\frac{(x)*(x+2)}{\left(1+x\right)^2}\right)\\
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=
\frac{\displaystyle 
\left(\frac{(x)*(x+2)}{\left(1+x\right)^2}\right)}
{\displaystyle
\left(\frac{(y)*(y+2)}{\left(1+y\right)^2}\right)}
= \frac{\displaystyle (x)*(x+2)}
       {\displaystyle (y)*(y+2)}
*\frac{\displaystyle \left(1+y\right)^2} 
                     {\left(1+x\right)^2}\\
= \frac{\displaystyle \left(1+y\right)^2}
       {\displaystyle (y)*(y+2)}
*\frac{\displaystyle (x)*(x+2)} 
                     {\left(1+x\right)^2}
$$
So:
$$
\left(\frac{dy}{dx} +
           \left(1+y\right)^2 
       \right)=0
\underset{implies}\implies
{\displaystyle -1}=
\frac{\displaystyle 1}
       {\displaystyle (y)*(y+2)}
*\frac{\displaystyle (x)*(x+2)} 
                     {\left(1+x\right)^2}
$$
And also: 
$$
\frac{\displaystyle dy}{\displaystyle dx}
= \frac{\displaystyle \left(1+y\right)^2}
       {\displaystyle (y)*(y+2)}
*\frac{\displaystyle (x)*(x+2)} 
                     {\left(1+x\right)^2}
=-\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\left(1+x\right)^2}
\\
\underset{implies}\implies
\frac{\displaystyle \left(1+y\right)^2}
       {\displaystyle (y)*(y+2)}
*\frac{\displaystyle (x)*(x+2)} 
                     {1}
={\displaystyle -1}
$$
$$\tag{Eq. 8}$$
Then the necessary condition is that:
$$\underset{implies}\implies (1+x)^2*(1+y)^2=1
\tag{Eq. 9}
$$

This follows the symmetry in Equations 2a. and 2b.

###### Conclusion

$$\underset{implies}{\implies}
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)
=    -\frac1{\left(1+x\right)^2} 
\tag{Eq. 10}$$